# foreach to linq tip wanted

Tags: c#, linq

How do I do this in linq?

```
var p = new pmaker();

 foreach (var item in itemlist)
 {
   var dlist = new List<Dummy>();
   foreach (var example in item.examples)
   { 
     dlist.Add(example.GetDummy()); 
   }
   p.AddStuff(item.X,item.Y,dlist);
 }

// .. do stuff with p
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
var qry = from item in itemlist
          select new {item.X, item.Y,
              Dummies = item.examples.Select(
                ex => ex.GetDummy())
          };
foreach (var item in qry)
{
    p.AddStuff(item.X, item.Y, item.Dummies.ToList());
}
```

Not sure it is much clearer like this, though... personally I think I might just use the original `foreach` version... maybe splitting out the `GetDummy` bit:

```
foreach (var item in itemlist)
{
    var dlist = item.examples.Select(ex => ex.GetDummy()).ToList();
    p.AddStuff(item.X,item.Y,dlist);
}
```

Comment: Learning when to not use LINQ is probably just as important as knowing when to use it :-)

Comment: The funny thing is that I've have downvotes before for pointing out when something isn't a good fit for LINQ... odd.

Answer (score 3):

if `itemlist` is a `List<T>` collection you could do:

```
var p = new pmaker();
itemlist.ForEach(item => 
  p.AddStuff(item.X, item.Y, 
      (from ex in item.examples
       select ex.GetDummy()).ToList())
);
```

but if it's clearer this way? I think not, you should not use LINQ and delegates just because you like to, but because it states the intent of your code better.

Answer (score 2):

Extending Marc's answer you could use `All` to add the items to p, but it's abusing `All` a bit unless `p.AddStuff` could fail.

```
(var qry = from item in itemlist
      select new {item.X, item.Y,
          Dummies = item.examples.Select(
            ex => ex.GetDummy())
      }).All(item=>{p.AddStuff(item.X, item.Y, item.Dummies.ToList()); return true;});
```

If `p.AddStuff` can fail and you wanted to be sure all the items were added it would be completely appropriate to do it like this:

```
bool allAdded = (var qry = from item in itemlist
      select new {item.X, item.Y,
          Dummies = item.examples.Select(
            ex => ex.GetDummy())
      }).All(item=>p.AddStuff(item.X, item.Y, item.Dummies.ToList()));
```